# rails error: not importing css files in specified orer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use the bootstrap skin from http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin-v2 in an app, well the nav menu really.

When I copy the css and js over to a rails project and run the server, I get an error message "Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix" - that variable is defined in a file _variables.scss, one of several style sheets in a sub-folder underneath app/assets/stylesheets

The code cauising the error is in another stylesheet in the same sub-folder (called app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome/scss).

In that folder are these files:

```
_bordered-pulled.scss
_core.scss
_fixed-width.scss
_icons.scss
_larger.scss
_list.scss
_mixins.scss
_path.scss
_rotated-flipped.scss
_spinning.scss
_stacked.scss
_variables.scss
font-awesome.scss
```

The error is

```
Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
  (in /Users/Nick/rails_projects/propcrm/app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome/scss/_bordered-pulled.scss:4)
```

font-awesome.scss contains:

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "larger";
@import "fixed-width";
@import "list";
@import "bordered-pulled";
@import "spinning";
@import "rotated-flipped";
@import "stacked";
@import "icons";
```

So I'm not sure why, with variables set to be the first to import the others don't have the variable references.

I tried reading the help doc on asset pipeline but it's greek to me. The download of the skin runs fine locally so I guess rails loads the css files in a different order(?). Any hints on how to work through this would be great. I've been digging at this for a couple of hours and it's beyond my ken.

Comment: I solved one of these problems before by refreshing the entire cache (Ctrl+Shift+R on Chrome), might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check `application.js` and see how they are being pulled in. If you are using a wildcard, I bet it's pulling them in alphabetical order. If so, see if you can be more specific or rename _variables.scss. The asset pipeline imports files from the main application file.